# IonScroll.scrollTop without scrolling

Tags: ionic3

I have  element which I want to initially set to certain scrollTop

The following code did not helped me:

```
this.scrollElement._scrollContent.nativeElement.scrollTop = 40;
```

Neither this:

```
this.scrollElement._scrollContent.nativeElement.scrollTo
({ left: 0, top: 40, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

This I'm setting in ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ion-slides for this purpose using the reference below:

https://market.ionicframework.com/plugins/ionic-timepicker-component

Answer (score 0):

> In your .html file

```
<ion-content #pageTop>
  <!-- Other content here -->
</ion-content>
```

> In your .ts file

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

//
//...
//

export class ScrollPage{
  @ViewChild('pageTop') pageTop: Content;

  /**
   * Method to scroll to top
   */
  public pageScroller(){
    //scroll to page top
    this.pageTop.scrollToTop();
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to do work around with ion-scroll only not the content